# How to Obtain OAuth Credentials with the Google Drive SDK 2 and Python without Human Interaction

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a Python application that fetches data from a third party source, selects a sub-set, and writes it to a CSV file which is then uploaded to Google Drive and converted to a spreadsheet.  I want to run this as a cron job, but currently the SDK needs a human to interact with a browser to obtain the OAuth credentials.

I've searched the Drive SDK docs and found nothing to help.  I also tried unsuccessfully to automate the OAuth  process with the mechanize library.  I'm sure I'm missing something.  I can't believe the Drive API requires human interaction.  Suggestions?

I've consulted https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#overview and this is what I tried.

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(settings.CLIENT_ID, settings.CLIENT_SECRET
                           setings.OAUTH_SCOPE,settings.REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
```

creates the request url:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&
redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&
response_type=code&
client_id=999637210521.apps.googleusercontent.com&
access_type=offline
```

Then using the requests library I issue:
    `r = req.get(authorize_url)`

but the response body is an HTML doc with no code.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue earlier.

Solution: Save credentials for future use. Refer following URLs:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#installed

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

```
from oauth2client.file import Storage
...
storage = Storage('a_credentials_file')
storage.put(credentials)
...
credentials = storage.get()
```

I pushed my script, in which I am reusing credentials for creating new tokens, to github.

https://github.com/sukujgrg/google_drive

Comment: You still have to interactively obtain the credentials the first time and when they expire, don't you?

It appears from the examples in the API docs that you should be able to get a response with the code in it as referenced in my initial example above.

Comment: Yes, first time we need human interaction. As long as the user has not revoked the access granted to the application, we don't need a human interaction. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#refresh

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the Authorization section on the Google Drive API? (https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python#authorization)

If that doesn't give you what you need, take a peek at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library. It's dead simple to use, and should allow you to get your OAuth creds pretty easily.

Comment: I read that and it has examples like:

<p>`code = self.request.get('code')`</p>

but what it the structure of the request?

Comment: Ok, I see. So have you gone to the [API Access Pane](https://code.google.com/apis/console#:access), and setup the project with a "Server Key"? The default key is a "Browser Key" and it was intended to be used by a human at a keyboard... which can still be faked with the python requests module. However the right way to do it is with a "Server Key" if you're going to set it up on Cron.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER:

I am not a security expert, and do not know the risks involved with my horrible solution to the problem... but it will get you code to be Cron runnable.

If you are willing to do the manual access acceptance one time to your app, with some given scope, as in the google quickstart example (Useful parts posted at bottom of answer ): https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python

Then you can ADD BOTH the `CLIENT_SECRET_FILE`  AND the `drive-quickstart.json` file that you generated once to your repository.  Then, if you have some google drive account where you always want ANY copy of your code base to have access to it, there is never a second check for credentials.

DISCLAIMER AGAIN:

Intuitively this solution is horrible for security, and the instant your code base is made public in ANY way, then your google drive is completely at risk for being destroyed, deleted, banned, etc...

```
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

def get_credentials():

    try:
        import argparse
        flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
    except ImportError:
        flags = None

    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    #ASSUME THAT THE CLIENT SECRETE FILE BELOW IS STORED IN YOUR CODE BASE
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Quickstart'

    #ASSUME THAT THIS FILE BELOW IS STORED INSIDE YOUR CODE BASE
    credential_dir = os.path.realpath('')
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatability with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def oneTimeRunCredentials():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
    results = service.files().list(maxResults=10).execute()
```

Comment: Once you have run this script once, and then added all three files to your code base -> your cron, and any other copies of your cron on other machines with this code base -> should run just fine.